# HTML5 Doctype + flex + overflow doesn't work as expected

Tags: css, html

I have:
Style

```
<style>
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
.layout{
    display: box;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
.layout-middle-row{
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
}
.layout-panel-center{
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}
div[class*="layout-panel"]
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div[class*="layout-panel"]>div[name="content"]{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;

}
.grid td{
    border:1px solid red;
}
.grid-cell{
    background-color: white;
    text-indent: 5px;
}
.grid-cell:hover {
    background-color: azure;
}
.multiview{
overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

And html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="layout">
    <div class="layout-middle-row">
        <div class="layout-panel-left" style="width:300px;">
            <div name="content">
                <div id="MainMenu_menuPanel" class="menuPanel">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layout-panel-center">
            <div name="content">
        <div id="AView" class="multiview" >
        <table class="grid">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>
        Column 1
        </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" class="grid-cell">1</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

What I need: A scrollbars to scroll a content of MULTIVIEW inside of CONTENT.

What I have: A scrollbar that is not active.

What I found: Removing "DOCTYPE html" solves that problem, scrollbar is activated, layout works as expected.

So, here's the question:

Am I missing something, or using html5 is supposed to be done with "DOCTYPE html", which is equivalent of html5's doctype? And this functionality suppose to work ONLY in html5 doctype?

If anyone can give me any hints at least about - why this is happening - that would be great.

## [Example](http://oligofriend.me.pn/trash_html.html)

Remove that upper line (DOCTYPE html) it will start to work as expected. Unfortunately jsfiddle was adding DOCTYPE ignoring DTD settings.

**Requirements**

1. It should work on browsers that support html5 standard
2. It doesn't have to work on IE
3. It shouldn't use Javascript (but it would be nice to see examples, if someone has such solution)

Answer (score 0):

*DISCLAIMER: My solution solved my own problem of flex not stretching a background  color across the rest of the page.

I experienced the same solution for flex. I found the problem was that Visual Studio Code's '!' shortcut for html documents was "" instead of "<! DOCTYPE html>"

(note the space between the exclamation point and DOCTYPE.)

When I added the space, my page rendered properly.

In addition, if I kept the default VS Code arrangement, but added a 5 after html, it also rendered correctly: .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
```

OR

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
```